# C++ показать вторую букву из слова

Tags: c++, c, массивы, строки

Привет. Нужна помощь с выводом определенных букв из слова.
Например есть 
char* moeslovo = "moeslovo";

как из moeslovo показать только определенную букву, например вторую, т.е. "o".
Буду рад готовому примеру, заранее благодарю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строка `char*` - не что иное, как массив символов. Массивы в C и C++ индексируются, начиная с нуля, так что то, что вы называете *вторым* символом, имеет индекс 1, а `k`-й символ в обыденном понимании - `k-1`-й, так что получить `k`-й символ можно как `moeslovo[k-1]`.

Если же вопрос в "показать", то нужно использовать один из массы способов. Например,

```
putchar(moeslovo[k-1]);     // Работает и в C, и в C++
printf("%c",moeslovo[k-1]); // Работает и в C, и в C++

cout << moeslovo[k-1];      // Работает только в C++
```

В силу способов использования указателей можно обращаться к букве и как

```
cout << *(moeslovo+k-1);
```

или даже

```
cout << *(k-1+moeslovo);
cout << (k-1)[moeslovo];
```

Comment: Пользуясь случаем, спрошу ещё как сделать программно букву заглавной. Например есть char* bukvak = "k"; Нужно сделать, чтобы отображалась как "K", а не "k"

Comment: См. тут: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper

Comment: Честно говоря не очень силен в английском, можете так же пожалуйста готовый пример с буквой К?

Comment: Кстати с локалями не вариант, у меня слова берутся с сервера, которые независимо от локали будут отображаться именно так, как на сервере

Comment: В совершенно общем виде задача нерешаема - обязательно нужно, чтоб правильно поддерживались локали... Иначе проще составить свою таблицу :) А использовать - ну, вместо `putchar(moeslovo[k-1]);` написать `putchar(toupper(moeslovo[k-1]));`

Answer (score 3):

```
char* moeslovo = "moeslovo";

std::cout << moeslovo[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << *(moeslovo+1) << std::endl;
```